# How to Select only one unique record from the Table using Distinct

Tags: oracle, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

my table have several records which has the same MemberID. i want to result out only one record.

```
select DISTINCT(MemberID)  from AnnualFees;
```

then result will come. but i want to show the other column data also but when i do this

```
select DISTINCT(MemberID),StartingDate,ExpiryDate,Amount  from AnnualFees;
```

all the details including same MemberID data also displaying.

can someone help me.

Comment: So how do you want to choose WHICH of the many AnnualFees rows for MemberID=123 should be displayed?  Or do you just want any one random row?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming you just want any row at random for each memberid than you can do this:

```
select memberid, this, that, theother
from
(
select memberid, this, that, theother,
       row_number() over (partition by memberid order by this) rn
from   annualfees
)
where rn = 1;
```

If you wanted a specific row per memberid, e.g. the one with the most recent StartDate then you could modify it to:

```
select memberid, this, that, theother
from
(
select memberid, this, that, theother,
       row_number() over (partition by memberid order by StartDate desc) rn
from   annualfees
)
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: RE: Your last query. Do you happen to know whether that is more efficient in Oracle than the version in my answer?

Comment: @Martin Smith: The analytics solution (Tony's) will make a single pass on the data whereas yours will add a self-join (which may be a small overhead but will add work nonetheless). **In general**, Tony's solution will therefore be more efficient.

Comment: @Vincent Thanks, I was wondering about the row_number calculation. I presume that on the single pass it must create a bucket for each memberid, fill it with start dates and row ids, and then sort each bucket. If so I can see that would be quicker. If this guess as to how it works is totally wrong someone let me know!

Comment: @Martin: One advantage of your solution is that Oracle doesn't have to read ALL rows of `annualfees` before returning rows: it can return rows as it finds those that satisfy the where clause whereas the analytics solution will have to read **ALL** rows before returning the first batch. If you are interested only in the first few rows (and if the table is really big), you will find your query returns faster. *(as always there is a tradeoff)*

Answer (score 6):

don't know if this is quite what you need, but you may need to look at GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT...

**if you have several records with the same member id, you may need to specify exaclty how to identify the one you want from the others**

**eg to get each member`s last starting date:**

```
SELECT memberid, max(startingdate)
FROM annualfees
GROUP BY memberid
```

but if you need to identify one record in this kind of way but also display the other columns, i think [you may need to do some trickery like this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)...

**eg sub-query the above SELECT with a join to join the other columns you want:**

```
SELECT subq.memid, subq.startdate, a.expirydate, a.amount
FROM (
  SELECT memberid AS memid, max(startingdate) AS startdate
  FROM annualfees
  GROUP BY memberid ) subq
INNER JOIN annualfees a ON a.memberid = subq.memid 
               AND a.startingdate = subq.startdate
```

**from start to finish, also showing data table (o/p was traced/grabbed using "SET VERIFY ON")...**

```
-- show all rows
select *
from annualfees
order by memberid, startingdate
MEMBERID               STARTINGDATE              EXPIRYDATE           AMOUNT               
---------------------- ------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- 
1                      02-DEC-09                 05-FEB-10            111                  
1                      25-JUN-10                 25-JUN-11            222                  
2                      25-APR-10                 25-JUN-13            333                  

3 rows selected

/
-- show one member`s data using max(startingdate) as selector.
SELECT memberid, max(startingdate)
    FROM annualfees
    GROUP BY memberid
MEMBERID               MAX(STARTINGDATE)         
---------------------- ------------------------- 
1                      25-JUN-10                 
2                      25-APR-10                 

2 rows selected

/ 
-- show above data joined with the other columns.
SELECT subq.memid, subq.startdate, a.expirydate, a.amount
    FROM (
      SELECT memberid AS memid, max(startingdate) AS startdate
      FROM annualfees
      GROUP BY memberid ) subq
    INNER JOIN annualfees a ON a.memberid = subq.memid AND a.startingdate = subq.startdate
MEMID                  STARTDATE                 EXPIRYDATE           AMOUNT               
---------------------- ------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- 
1                      25-JUN-10                 25-JUN-11            222                  
2                      25-APR-10                 25-JUN-13            333                  

2 rows selected

/
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to select which of the rows with duplicate MemberIDs to return in some way. This will get the row with the greatest startingDate.

```
SELECT MemberID,StartingDate,ExpiryDate,Amount 
FROM AnnualFees af
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * from AnnualFees af2 
        WHERE af2.MemberID = af.MemberID 
        AND af2.StartingDate > af.StartingDate)
```

Answer (score -3):

select DISTINCT MemberID,StartingDate,ExpiryDate,Amount from AnnualFees;

remove paranthesis

Comment: This will return one row for *every permutation* of MemberID,StartingDate,ExpiryDate and Amount